# What is the use of which php in Bash?

Tags: php, bash

I do find in few codes that

```
php=`which php`
```

what is the use of this command in bash. What does it do?
What will happen if we did not use it?

Comment: The command shows you the symlinked location of your php whenever you type `php`, the re-defining of `php` might change the result after the first time

Comment: I suggest: `man which`

Comment: What shall it happen if we don't use it?

Comment: You will need to manually give the full path of php if you want to use someother php than default one installed in your `PATH`. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means where is php located and which one to be selected if there are multiple php installations. And probably it is one with backticks rather than single quotes like

```
php=`which php`
```

so if your highest precedence php is located at  `/usr/bin/php`, `php` variable will be assigned that value.

Comment: If there is only default PHP installation and is in the default path, then we may not need this. Isn't it?

Comment: usually no you don't need it then.